# R: escape single quote for SQLite with gsub (avoiding double escaping already escaped strings)

Tags: r, regex, sqlite

I need to escape strings of text to insert them in an SQLite database.

The problem is in my pipeline I might have already escaped strings. I need to take care of the possibility of `''`.

For example,

```
string1 <- "On the Internet, nobody knows I'm a dog"
string2 <- "On the Internet, nobody knows I''m a dog"
gsub("'", "''", string1)
# [1] "On the Internet, nobody knows I''m a dog"
```

but

```
gsub("'", "''", string2)
# [1] "On the Internet, nobody knows I''''m a dog"
```

Also

```
gsub("([^'])'[^']", "'", string2)
# "On the Internet, nobody knows I''m a dog"
```

but

```
gsub("([^'])'[^']", "'", string1)
# [1] "On the Internet, nobody knows ' a dog"
```

Comment: @hrbrmstr Actually, I don't.

Comment: This is a messy business that you can avoid by using parameterized queries with the `RODBCext` package.

Answer (score 1):

Look-ahead/behinds are one way to go (and the more optimal way), but you can also be a bit more brute-force-ish about it (if you're willing to process the text twice):

```
library(stringi)
library(magrittr)

txt_vals <- c("On the Internet, nobody knows I'm a dog's dog",
              "On the Internet, nobody knows I''m a dog's dog")

stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(txt_vals, "''", "'") %>% 
  stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("'", "''")
```

You should prbly accept the first working look-ahead/look-behind solution vs this one, but this shld get you going in the mean time.

Comment: This seems to replace only the first occurrence of a quotation: `stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("On the Internet, nobody knows I'm a dog's dog", regex, "$1''$2")` returns `"On the Internet, nobody knows I''m a dog's dog"`

Answer (score 1):

A positive-lookbehind solution that user hrbmstr mentioned based on this regex: `(?<=')'`:

```
string1 <- "On the Internet, nobody knows I'm a dog"
string2 <- "On the Internet, nobody knows I''m a dog"
string3 <- "On the Internet, nobody knows I'm a dog's dog"
string4 <- "On the Internet, nobody knows I''m a dog''s dog"
string5 <- "Weird Al'''s apostrophes"
gsub("(?<=')'", "", string1, perl=TRUE)
gsub("(?<=')'", "", string2, perl=TRUE)
gsub("(?<=')'", "", string3, perl=TRUE)
gsub("(?<=')'", "", string4, perl=TRUE)
gsub("(?<=')'", "", string5, perl=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
"On the Internet, nobody knows I'm a dog"
"On the Internet, nobody knows I'm a dog"
"On the Internet, nobody knows I'm a dog's dog"
"On the Internet, nobody knows I'm a dog's dog"
"weird al's apostrophes"
```

Answer (score 1):

While using parameterized queries with the [RODBCext package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/index.html) will do the job properly, a solution to only replace uneven number of quotes with a regex can be achieved with the following PCRE regex:

```
x <- c("On the Internet, nobody knows I'm a dog", "On the Internet, '''nobody''' knows I''m a ''''dog''''")
gsub("''(*SKIP)(?!)|'", "''", x, perl=TRUE)
## 
## [1] "On the Internet, nobody knows I''m a dog"                
## [2] "On the Internet, ''''nobody'''' knows I''m a ''''dog''''"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ar1YU/1) and an  [R demo](http://ideone.com/4zNaCe).

**Details**:

- `''`  - two consecutive singel quotes
- `(*SKIP)(?!)` - special PCRE verb and a negative lookahead sequence that makes the regex engine skip the consumed text and go on matching from the end of the text discarded
- `|`  - or
- `'` - a single quote.